Problem running eclipse jee 2024-09 in windows 8.1
On my laptop having Windows 8.1 I've downloaded eclipse-jee-2024-09-R-win32-x86_64.zip.
Then I unpacked it and I try to run eclipse.exe.
In my system there is Java 23.0.1.
I obtain the above error:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    C:\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\800\0\.cp\swt-win32-4966r5.dll: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata
    no swt-win32 in java.library.path: C:\eclipse;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_21.0.4.v20240802-1551/jre/bin/server;C:/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_21.0.4.v20240802-1551/jre/bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Users\Franco\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\eclipse;;.
    no swt in java.library.path: C:\eclipse;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_21.0.4.v20240802-1551/jre/bin/server;C:/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_21.0.4.v20240802-1551/jre/bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Users\Franco\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\eclipse;;.
    C:\Users\Franco\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-win32-4966r5.dll: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata
    Can't load library: C:\Users\Franco\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-win32.dll
    Can't load library: C:\Users\Franco\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt.dll
    C:\Users\Franco\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-win32-4966r5.dll: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata

Really all these files are present in a indicated directory.
How can I resolve the problem?

Verify your Java architecture as your OS arch. and it's correct path in Eclipse.ini file in your Eclipse program root folder... all good?

Probably this Windows 8 is no longer supported as SWT now uses APIs that are not in Windows 8.

Yes, as greg-449 mentions it is a problem with old OSs. I faced the same with win7

In eclipse.ini the startup command refere ay plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.900.v20240613-2009.jar
and also
plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_21.0.4.v20240802-1551/jre/bin
in addition to other internal plugins.
It's the one present in the zip file downloaded.
I cannot change the Windows version; if I try to use an old version of Eclipse it's possibile?
And which version I can try to use?

If you read the link I gave the problem report says 2024-06 worked ok so try that.

I've tried to download eclipse-jee-2024-06-R-win32-x86_64.zip with the same result.
I's possible that it depends of the java version that is more recent (the last)?

I've tried to install the execute version of 2024-03 and it run. Best regards.
